# Sharepoint Azure AD authentication

Tags: c#, sharepoint, azure-active-directory

How can I access documents from SharePoint library path using C# console application. Configured SharePoint on premise authentication with Azure AD for remote access.

Before configured, C# console application can access documents from SharePoint library path using SharePoint Client Object Model (CSOM).

Here is sample code:

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext(RootLibraryPath);
SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in Password.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, passWord);
context.ExecuteQuery();

Web web = context.Web;
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>" +
                   "<Query>" +
                   "</Query>" +
                 "</View>";

List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryName);
ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
context.Load(items);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could call SharePoint Online APIs (via REST or CSOM)  with Azure Active Directory Apps . To call APIS secured by Azure AD , your app must acquire an access token from Azure Active Directory (Azure AD), Microsoft's cloud identity service.

Please firstly refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications) for integrating applications with Azure Active Directory . And then use [Azure Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) to easily authenticate users to cloud or on-premises Active Directory (AD), and obtain access tokens for securing API calls. Also [here](https://stephaneeyskens.wordpress.com/2015/08/01/using-csom-with-azure-active-directory-apps/) 
 and  [here](https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/02/27/using-adal-access-tokens-with-o365-rest-apis-and-csom/) are documents for how to use CSOM with Azure Active Directory Apps .